# SQLAlchemy hybrid method as an attribute in the query result?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In a search for more syntactically pleasant models, I've created something like (omitted not so relevant parts):

```
class Post(BaseModel):
    acl = db.relationship("ACL", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

    @hybrid_method
    def is_editable_by(self, user):
        if user_is_admin(user):
            return True
        else:
            return any(acl.user_id == user.id for acl in self.acl)

    @is_editable_by.expression
    def is_editable_by(cls, user):
        if user_is_admin(user):
            return true().label("is_editable")
        else:
            return and_(true(), cls.acl.any(user_id=user.id)).label("is_editable")
```

That works nicely with a query like:

```
results = db.session.query(Post, Post.is_editable_by(current_user)).all()
usage = [(item.Post.name, item.is_editable) for item in results]
```

However, I am getting a list of tuples, so the question is: Does SQLAlchemy has any mechanism to make it one object (some kind of proxy/adapter maybe)? If it were not for a parameter (user), hybrid_property would be exact answer:

```
[(item.name, item.is_editable) for item in results]
```

It is possible to make the desirable with yet another class, but I wonder if ORM has something already for this case? The main idea is when a lot of objects are obtained, there is no need to calculate something for each object. Or at least that calculation will not require extra calls to the database. In other words, how to have result objects with some derived attributes, which depend on some parameter?

Maybe there is totally different pattern for this kind of thing. This case is in some sense similar to `load_only`, but it's about adding a "virtual" column to an object, not removing.

Could also be nice with version 0.9 of SQLAlchemy...

Subtlety:

```
results = db.session.query(Post, Post.is_editable_by(user1)).all()
[(item.name, item.is_editable) for item in results]
...
results = db.session.query(Post, Post.is_editable_by(user2)).all()
[(item.name, item.is_editable) for item in results]
```

should not cause problems.

Comment: Maybe something like https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#query-time-sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes?

Comment: Oh, missed the version requirement, and also reading more carefully, why would you need to select the hybrid? The idea is that it's usable both in the query context *and in Python*.

Comment: I see, the `self.acl` access causes lazy fetches, right? Then the solution is to eagerly load those. This seems like an XY.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out query expressions. As for two contexts - in this case could be good to use both for multiple items as well as individually. What is XY?

Comment: Eager load probably not that good solution as the query is already quite involved... Luckily, EXISTS solves this nicely, so I just wondered if some syntactic sugar exists in SA.

Comment: Also, not sure how "with_expression" in this question's context can be ok if there are several users... AFAIK, SA keeps registry of objects.

Comment: Your example query does not include multiple users. I do get that you you'd like to use EXISTS in SQL instead of loading the ACL objects (eagerly or not) just so that the hybrid can go through them, but then the tuple approach is just fine. You could maybe use a [bundle](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_columns.html#bundles), but then you'd be giving up on the ORM features.

Comment: Well, I meant for example if same object will be a result in two consequent queries.

Comment: That's a valid concern (that I missed entirely), and then the answer is: use the tuple approach. In my opinion it's the cleanest in that case, since you're querying for the object and another fact about that object, but not strictly related to it and only it.

Comment: Thanks! I totally agree.