# SQLAlchemy: How to output a calculated field that takes in parameters from the user as input

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a model something like this:

```py
class User:
    __tablename__ = "user"

    first_name = Column(String(), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(), nullable=False)
```

I then have a query like this:

```py
name = ["...", ...]
user_query = (
    db.session.query(User)
    .add_column(case([
        (and_(User.first_name).ilike(f'%{name}%'), User.last_name.ilike(f'%{name}%')), True),
        (or_(User.first_name).ilike(f'%{name}%'), User.last_name.ilike(f'%{name}%')), False)
    ]).label('perfect_match'))
    .order_by(literal_column("'perfect_match'"))
)
```

This is obviously an over-simplification, but essentially I'm trying to do a search across fields and sort the perfect matches separately from the imperfect matches.

This is giving me an error saying that the column "perfect_match" doesn't exist, so I think I'm using `add_column` incorrectly here.

I also tried using `hybrid_method` like so:

```py
@hybrid_method
def perfect_match(self, terms):
    perfect_match = True
    matched = False
    for term in terms:
        if term.lower() in self.first_name.lower() or term.lower() in self.last_name.lower():
            matched = True
            continue
        perfect_match = False

    return perfect_match if matched else None

@perfect_match.expression
def perfect_match(self, terms):
    perfect_match = and_(...)
    imperfect_match = or_(...)

    return case(...)
```

And then my query looks like this:

```py
name = [...]
user_query = (
    db.session.query(User)
    .filter(User.perfect_match(name) != None)
    .order_by(User.perfect_match(name))
```

I want `perfect_match` to be in the output. Here's my desired SQL:

```sql
SELECT
    first_name,
    last_name,
    case (
        ...
    ) as perfect_match
FROM user
WHERE perfect_match != NULL
ORDER BY perfect_match
```

The first using `add_column` gives me that SQL, but SQLAlchemy errors saying it can't column `perfect_match` does not exist. The second (using `hybrid_method`) puts the case in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses (probably inefficient?) and doesn't include perfect_match in the output, but it does seem to be working properly. I need to use that output column to determine where the perfect matches end.

I've tried:

- adding perfect_match as a Column(Boolean)
- adding perfect_match as a column_property()
- adding perfect_match as .query(User, literal_column("'perfect_match'"))

Any thoughts? Most of the examples I've seen use `hybrid_property`, but I need to take in an argument here. I'm pretty new to SQLAlchemy, so I probably missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, needed a virtual/property based on a parameter only available during runtime, just a boolean value.

I tried this [SQLAlchemy hybrid method as an attribute in the query result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59424867/sqlalchemy-hybrid-method-as-an-attribute-in-the-query-result) and it didn't work, I wanted the conversion from model to schema to be more direct so I did this.

Define a column named **perfect_match** as `query_expression()` in your model:

```
class User(BaseModel):
    ...
    perfect_match = query_expression()
    ...
```

Then when building the query or statement, define an expression, in your case:

```
exp = case([
    (and_(User.first_name).ilike(f'%{name}%'), User.last_name.ilike(f'%{name}%')), True),
    (or_(User.first_name).ilike(f'%{name}%'), User.last_name.ilike(f'%{name}%')), False)])
query = (
    db.session.query(User)
    .options(with_expression(User.perfect_match, exp))
    .filter(User.perfect_match(name) != None)
    .order_by(User.perfect_match(name)
)
return query.all()
```

It works using statements also, same syntax. Pydantic should recognize that field as a *column*.